# Custom validation not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I wrote my own basic validation:

```
 validate :valid_date, allow_blank: true  
 .....

   private
def valid_date
    a = geburtsdatum.split('.')
    Date.valid_date?(a[2],a[1],a[0])
end
```

The params that are passed to the the method in my post request are:

```
 {"patient"=>{"vorname"=>"sdfss", "name"=>"sdf", "geburtsdatum"=>"45.23.1994"}}
```

But somehow it wont work i get this error:

```
 undefined method `split' for nil:NilClass
```

Means that i dont access the param `geburtsdatum` correctly! How can i fix this? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add an error inside the validator:

```
def valid_date
  a = geburtsdatum.split('.')
  errors.add(:<invalid_field_name>, 'is invalid') unless Date.valid_date?(a[2],a[1],a[0])
end
```

`valid?` method in short do: 1. Run validations, 2. Return `errors.any?`

Comment: Sorry but i get the same error! `geburtsdatum` is nil! Dont you think i have to access geburtsdatum as param?

Comment: Ah, this has nothing to do with a validation. Could you show your controller action assigning this params to model?

Comment: No its a validation in my model: `validate :valid_date, allow_blank: true  `

Comment: Yes, but validation is failing because the param was assgined incorrectly. TO find out why I need to see the assignment.